# How to change the colour of a wire frame in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shapes

I have a letter, which I converted into a wire frame, now I want to change the colour of wireframe, but no reliable option found so far.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! It would be most helpful if you could add some screenshots and show us what you have tried and where exactly you get stuck. This saves everybody time, and makes it more likely that you will get helpful answers.

Comment: Please explain "Converted into a wire frame". What does that mean???

Comment: @Vincent, I don't know how you can edit the question to include reference to the 3D effect unless you're attempting to edit it to fit *your* answer. **SimmM never posted anything about 3D.** "Convert to wireframes" could simply mean created outlines and added a stroke, removing the fill. This is why I specifically asked for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've merely created outlines of the type to generate your 'Wireframe" then simply change the stroke color.

If you have indeed used the `3D Effect` and set it to "wireframe", then do the following:

1. Group the type
2. Add a new stroke via Appearance panel above the [content] item in the panel
3. Change the color of this new stroke

With these steps the 3D effect and the type both **remain live and editable** but the wireframe color changes.

If you've used some other method to "covert into a wireframe" you need to explain what you've done.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going out on a limb and suppose you've created the wireframe using the `Effect > 3D > Extrude & Bevel` effect. In that case:

Unfortunately, there is no way of doing this and keep the `3D` effect editable. You can `Object > Expand Appearance` the wireframe object, and then change the stroke colour on the resulting group of lines.

Comment: Thank you Vincent for the support. Actually I tried the method you specified, but I am not getting the desired results,the wireframe is getting bolder after doing that. I just changed the stroke colour, which finally helped.